# I cannot pass the test to dynamically change the value of the input tag when i clicked the button

Tags: reactjs, input, jestjs, react-testing-library

## My App Code

```
export function App() {
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState("");
    const inputRef = React.useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

    const handleClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (inputRef.current) {
            inputRef.current.value = inputRef.current.value + "1";
            setInputValue(inputRef.current.value);
        }
    };

    return (
        <form>
            <label htmlFor="password-input" >
                비밀번호
            </label>
            <input
                ref={inputRef}
                type="password"
                id="password-input"
                name="password-input"
                value={inputValue}
            />
            <button
                className="insert"
                data-testId={1}
                onClick={(e) => { handleClick(e) }}>
                입력
            </button>
        </form>)
}
```

## My test code

```js
test("Does clicking the button change the input value?", async () => {
        render(<App />);

        userEvent.click(await screen.findByTestId(1));
        userEvent.click(await screen.findByTestId(1));

        expect((await screen.findByLabelText<HTMLInputElement>(`비밀번호`)).value).toHaveLength(2);

        userEvent.click(await screen.findByTestId(1));
        userEvent.click(await screen.findByTestId(1));
        userEvent.click(await screen.findByTestId(1));
        userEvent.click(await screen.findByTestId(1));

        expect((await screen.findByLabelText<HTMLInputElement>(`비밀번호`)).value).toHaveLength(6);
    })
```

## As a result of running the test code is

```
    expect(received).toHaveLength(expected)

    Expected length: 2
    Received length: 1
    Received string: "1"

      37 |         userEvent.click(await screen.findByTestId(1));
      38 |
    > 39 |         expect((await screen.findByLabelText<HTMLInputElement>(`비밀번호`)).value).toHaveLength(2);
         |                                                                                ^
      40 |
      41 |         userEvent.click(await screen.findByTestId(1));
      42 |         userEvent.click(await screen.findByTestId(1));

      at Object.toHaveLength (src/test/my.spec.tsx:39:80)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
```

Every time I clicked on a button, i expected the input value to be "1", "11" and "111" from "", but it seems to work on dev server, but when i ran the test code, the input value continued to be less than the number of clicks. How can i fix thi error and pass the test?
Please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- It should be `data-testid`, not `data-testId`.
- [click()](https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/convenience#click) API returns a promise, so you need to use it like `await useEvent.click()`.
- There is no need to use `data-testid`, you can find the button element by its accessible role(`'button'`) with accessible name(`'입력'`)

e.g.

`index.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';

export function App() {
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState('');
    const inputRef = React.useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

    const handleClick = (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (inputRef.current) {
            inputRef.current.value = inputRef.current.value + '1';
            setInputValue(inputRef.current.value);
        }
    };

    return (
        <form>
            <label htmlFor='password-input'>비밀번호</label>
            <input ref={inputRef} type='password' id='password-input' name='password-input' value={inputValue} />
            <button
                className='insert'
                onClick={(e) => {
                    handleClick(e);
                }}
            >
                입력
            </button>
        </form>
    );
}
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { App } from '.';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';

test('Does clicking the button change the input value?', async () => {
    render(<App />);

    const $button = screen.getByRole('button', { name: '입력' });

    await userEvent.click($button);
    await userEvent.click($button);

    let $passwordInput = (await screen.findByLabelText(`비밀번호`)) as HTMLInputElement;

    expect($passwordInput.value).toHaveLength(2);

    await userEvent.click($button);
    await userEvent.click($button);
    await userEvent.click($button);
    await userEvent.click($button);

    expect($passwordInput.value).toHaveLength(6);
    expect($passwordInput.value).toBe('111111');
});
```

Test result:

```bash
  console.error
    Warning: Failed prop type: You provided a `value` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultValue`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`.
        in input (created by App)
        in form (created by App)
        in App

      at printWarning (node_modules/prop-types/checkPropTypes.js:20:15)

 PASS  stackoverflow/76865066/index.test.tsx (6.41 s)
  ✓ Does clicking the button change the input value? (116 ms)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |     100 |       50 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.tsx |     100 |       50 |     100 |     100 | 9                 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        6.619 s, estimated 7 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
```

package versions:

```json
"@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
"jest": "^26.6.3",
```